# Bootstrap self-center applying only on some elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make "navbar/toolbar" which has one item at left (`h3`) and 3 items on right (`a`, `a` and `select`). The problem is that I want them all to be vertically centered which is working only on my first item (`h3`). Why it is like that?

This is the example:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="align-self-center">
          <h3 class="pl-4">
            Title
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto">
          <a class="" href="javascript:void();">
            1
          </a>
          <a class="" href="javascript:void();">
            2
          </a>
          <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
            <select class="form-control" >
              <option>1</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How should I align everything center vertically? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Only your h3 is in the div with the class `align-self-center`

Comment: you should have to take those three items in different column **h3** in one column **1** in another column and **2** also in another column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `align-self-center` on div which enclosing anchor tags and select. Also remove class `form-group` from the div which enclosing select because it's applying `margin-bottom` on select and because of that it does not seem to be in the center.
Here is the code changes which I explained:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="align-self-center">
                        <h3 class="pl-4">
                            Title
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ml-auto align-self-center">
                        <a class="" href="javascript:void();">
                            1
                        </a>
                        <a class="" href="javascript:void();">
                            2
                        </a>
                        <div style="display: inline-block;">
                            <select class="form-control" >
                                <option>1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining and sharing the only working version in my context. But what if you add icon into the link instead of just plain text?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the "align-self-center" class. check updated code.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding:20px;">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div>
          <h3 class="pl-4">
            Title
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto">
          <a class="" href="javascript:void();">
            1
          </a>
          <a class="" href="javascript:void();">
            2
          </a>
          <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
            <select class="form-control" >
              <option>1</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `align-self-center` class to parent div that contains all child

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="d-flex align-self-center">
       
          <h3 class="pl-4">
            Title
          </h3>
       
        <div class="ml-auto">
          <a class="" href="javascript:void();">
            1
          </a>
          <a class="" href="javascript:void();">
            2
          </a>
          <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
            <select class="form-control" >
              <option>1</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you changed ;)